# Calculate multiple shifts time difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server. Please tell me how to solve login and logout time calculation in SQL Server based on conditions.

1. if same `empid` will work multiple shifts, multiple shifts calculation for same date must be time difference is 5 hours then that date consider as multiple shifts for that emp
2. OnFloor time  how much time he spend
3. OffFloor time how much time he spend
4. if logout is missed then consider as taligate is 1 or -1

Sample input data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emplogindetails]
(
    [Emp ID] [float] NULL,
    [Area Of Access] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T09:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-02T10:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T09:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T12:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T12:40:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T17:10:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T06:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T08:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-05T23:30:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T01:55:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T02:15:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T06:10:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T11:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-02T12:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T14:01:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T15:01:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-06T15:20:00.000' AS DateTime))

INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) 
VALUES (1, N'K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-06T20:01:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Based on above data 4 th dates is holiday and he entered 5th date night shift and logout 6th date and same 6 th date he did another shift.

I want an output like below:

```
ShiftDate   |ShitStartTime              |ShiftEndTime               |Total_Time |OnFloor    |OffFloor   |EmpID  |Incount     |OutCount  |Tailgate
08/05/2017  |2017-08-05 23:30:00.000    |2017-08-06 06:10:00.000    |6:40:00    |06:00:00   |00:40:00   |1      |2           |   2      |   0
08/02/2017  |2017-08-02 09:00:00.000    |2017-08-02 13:00:00.000    |04:00:00   |02:30:00   |01:30:00   |1      |3           |   2      |   1
08/03/2017  |2017-08-03 06:30:00.000    |2017-08-03 17:10:00.000    |10:40:00   |09:30:00   |01:10:00   |1      |3           |   3      |   0
08/06/2017  |2017-08-06 14:01:00.000    |2017-08-06 20:01:00.000    |6:00:00    |05:10:00   |00:50:00   |1      |2           |   2      |   0
```

I tried like this:

```
select
  isnull( ShiftDate ,'1900-01-01')as ShiftDate , 
  isnull( min(logintime) ,'1900-01-01') as ShitStartTime,
   max( case when   logouttime is null  then '1900-01-01' else logouttime  end  )ShiftEndTime ,

 convert(varchar(8),dateadd(ss,sum(datediff(second,0,dateadd(day,0,Total_Time))),0),108) Total_Time,
  convert(varchar(8),dateadd(ss,sum(datediff(second,0,dateadd(day,0,OnFloor))),0),108) OnFloor,

  convert(varchar(8),dateadd(ss,sum(datediff(second,0,dateadd(day,0,OffFloor))),0),108) OffFloor,

 EmpID ,Incount ,OutCount, Tailgate
  from ( 
select 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (  OffFloor  +  cast ( OnFloor as int)) / 60 / 60 % 24) 
 +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor +  cast ( OnFloor as int)) / 60 % 60)
 +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor +  cast ( OnFloor as int))  % 60) as Total_Time 
,case when convert( varchar(10),OnFloor )='0' then '0:0:0' else OnFloor end OnFloor
,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (OffFloor) / 60 / 60 % 24)  +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor) / 60 % 60) 
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor)  % 60) AS OffFloor
  ,[Emp ID] ,[Area Of Access],status,logintime,logouttime 
from ( 
select    isnull( DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.logintime, a.logouttime) ,0) OffFloor , cast ( '0' as varchar) as OnFloor
,[Emp ID] ,[Area Of Access],status,logintime,logouttime 
 from ( 
 SELECT o.time logouttime,i.Time logintime,i.[Emp ID] 
,substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('out',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access])) status
              ,i.[Area Of Access]
              FROM    test.dbo.emplogindetails i  left join test.dbo.emplogindetails o
              on i.[emp id] = o.[emp id]
              AND CONVERT(date, i.time) = CONVERT(date, o.time)
              AND o.time > i.time
              AND substring ( o.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('in',o.[Area Of Access]),len(o.[Area Of Access]))='in'
              and substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('out',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access]))='out'

              and o.Time=(SELECT MIN(o2.time)
                                 FROM test.dbo.emplogindetails   o2
                                 WHERE o2.time > i.time 
                                 and o2.[Emp ID]=i.[Emp ID]
                                 ---and [emp id]='105828' 
                                 )
--where i.[emp id]='105828' 
)a where a.status='out')a
union all
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (OffFloor +  OnFloor) / 60 / 60 % 24) 
  +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor +  OnFloor) / 60 % 60) 
  +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OffFloor +  OnFloor) % 60) as Calculated_Time 
  ,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (OnFloor) / 60 / 60 % 24)  
  +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OnFloor) / 60 % 60)+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (OnFloor)  % 60) AS OnFloor
  , case when convert( varchar(10),OffFloor) ='0' then '0:0:0' else OffFloor end OffFloor


 ,[Emp ID] ,[Area Of Access],
status,logintime,logouttime
from (  
select   '0' as OffFloor, isnull( DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.logintime, a.logouttime) ,0) OnFloor 

,[Emp ID] ,[Area Of Access],status
,logintime,logouttime
 from ( 
 SELECT o.time logouttime,i.Time logintime,i.[Emp ID] 
,substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('in',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access])) status
              ,i.[Area Of Access]
              FROM    test.dbo.emplogindetails i  left join test.dbo.emplogindetails o
              on i.[emp id] = o.[emp id]
              AND CONVERT(date, i.time) = CONVERT(date, o.time)
              AND o.time > i.time
              AND substring ( o.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('out',o.[Area Of Access]),len(o.[Area Of Access]))='out'
              and substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('in',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access]))='in'

              and o.Time=(SELECT MIN(o2.time)
                                 FROM test.dbo.emplogindetails   o2
                                 WHERE o2.time > i.time 
                                 and o2.[Emp ID]=i.[Emp ID]
                                ---and [emp id]='105828'
                                  )
---where i.[emp id]='105828' 
)a where a.status='in')stag)stag

join 
----get incount and outcount and tailgate information

(select [emp id]as empid,incount,outcount,
isnull( incount-outcount ,0) as Tailgate ,Date as ShiftDate
from ( 
select  
i.[Emp ID] ,convert(varchar(10),time,101) as Date,
count( case  when substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('in',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access]))='in'
then   'in' end  )Incount
,count( case  when substring ( i.[Area Of Access] ,charindex('out',i.[Area Of Access]),len(i.[Area Of Access]))='out'
then   'out' end  )outcount
FROM    test.dbo.emplogindetails i
--where  [emp id]='105828' 
group by i.[Emp ID],convert(varchar(10),time,101)
)cnt)cnt
 on stag.[Emp ID]=cnt.empid and convert(varchar(10),stag.logintime,101)=cnt.ShiftDate

 group by EmpID ,Incount ,OutCount, Tailgate
  ,isnull( ShiftDate ,'1900-01-01')
```

This query is not returning the expected result when same date have multiple shifts calculation if logout and login time difference more than 5 hours then consider as next shift.
as per given below logic not working for empid=5 and data looking like below.
Hi ,one records is failed as per our logic .some changes is required in logic. I  did not get expected ouput for below example.

```
   INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-02T23:30:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'   K4FWhite Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T01:30:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T01:40:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'K4F White Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T04:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'K4F White Rm IN', CAST(N'2017-08-03T04:30:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplogindetails] ([Emp ID], [Area Of Access], [Time]) VALUES (5, N'K4F White Rm OUT', CAST(N'2017-08-03T06:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This query returns your expected output

```
select
    cast(ShitStartTime as date) ShiftDate, ShitStartTime, ShiftEndTime
    , concat(right(concat('0', tTime/60), 2), ':', right(concat('0',tTime%60), 2)) Total_Time
    , concat(right(concat('0', onF/60), 2), ':', right(concat('0',onF%60), 2)) OnFloor
    , concat(right(concat('0', offF/60), 2), ':', right(concat('0',offF%60), 2)) OffFloor
    , [Emp Id], Incount, OutCount, Tailgate
from (
    select
        [Emp Id], min(Time) ShitStartTime, max(Time) ShiftEndTime, sum(iif([Area Of Access] = 'K4F White Rm IN', diff, 0)) onF
        , sum(iif([Area Of Access] = 'K4FWhite Rm OUT', diff, 0)) offF, sum(diff) tTime
        , sum(iif([Area Of Access] = 'K4F White Rm IN', 1, 0)) Incount
        , sum(iif([Area Of Access] = 'K4FWhite Rm OUT', 1, 0)) OutCount
        , max(Tailgate) Tailgate
    from (
        select
            *, datediff(mi, Time, lead(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id], group_ order by Time)) diff
            , iif(Time = max(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id], group_) and [Area Of Access] = 'K4F White Rm IN', 1, 0) Tailgate
        from (
            select
                *, sum(gr) over (partition by [Emp Id] order by Time rows unbounded preceding) group_
            from (
                select 
                    *, iif(datediff(hh, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp Id] order by Time), Time) <= 5, 0, 1) gr
                from 
                    emplogindetails
            ) t
        ) t
    ) t
    group by [Emp Id], group_
) t
```

Comment: Hi empid=5 is not given as per expected output.please tell me where need to change in the given logic.

Comment: I have not noticed your sample data for empid=5 when was writing the query. But there is something wrong in your expected output. How you want show start as 2017-02-08 and end as 2017-03-08? It's a month difference! And total time only 6,5 hours. Are you sure you want to get this?

Comment: HI empid=5 record clarification: he working on night shift, thatswhy its showing start date is 2017-02-08  and end date is 2017-03-08 and if u consider time difference is not more than 6 hours gap between two dates for that empid.we need that empid record also.please tell me where need to change in our logic.Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: what is your date format? yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm? I thought it is yyyy-mm-dd. So 2017-02-08 is 8 of Feb and 2017-03-08 is 8 of Mar. It's a month difference. But if yyyy-dd-mm how do you get 2017-08-05 23:30:00 and 2017-08-06 06:10:00 for empid=1? Then it is a month difference

Comment: Hi, I tested data with wrong format dates. actually date format is yyyy-mm-dd only.  its my side mistake.now i corrected correct format data .its working now for totaltime and onfllor but showing wrong values for  incount and outcount and offfloor value information. acctual empid=5 incount values is 3 and outcount values is 3 but its showing wrong values. can u tell me where we need change logic.Thanks.

Comment: I think problem with your column [Area Of Access]. For sample you are giving values '   K4FWhite Rm OUT' and 'K4F White Rm OUT'. Which are not same. And because of wrong comparisons result may differ